# pi-hole hangup when its dns and dhcp server

Tags: dhcp, dns

I just installed pi-hole on my Raspberry Pi to use it as a DNS server in my local network. My router does not allow me to set a custom DNS server, so what i do is disable the DHCP server on my router and configured pi-hole to be the DHCP server to (all with standard settings).

I gave the pi a static ip address of 192.168.1.3 in the routers settings and configured the DHCP server with pihole to hand out adresseses between 192.168.1.4 and 192.168.1.255.

This works fine until i restart either my router or the Raspberry Pi, then the raspberry pi hangs itself up and i cannot ping it anymore.
If i quickly turn on the DHCP server on the router the raspberry pi goes back on and i can turn off the DHCP on the router again and everything seems normal.

After reading up on the topic i also generated the following file to make sure the raspberry pi has the static ip address, and loops back to itself for the dns server, having googles dns server as a fallback.

```
# /etc/dhcpcd.conf

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.3/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Sadly this does not solve my problem. What am i missing here?